# From python converter for builtin types

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

Where does boost python register from python converters for builtin types such as from `PyLong_Type` to `double`?

I want to define a converter that can take a `numpy.float128` from python and returns a `long double` for functions in C++. I already did it the other way round, the to_python converter. For that I tweaked `builtin_converters.hpp` but I didn't find how boost python does the from python conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The from python conversion is in fact done in `builtin_converters.cpp` and not in the header part of the library. I Copied this file and deleted everything except the converter for `long double`, which I was then able to modify.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to this answer, although for a slightly different problem:

*How can you convert Python type objects (that is, `PyTypeObject` such as `PyLong_Type`, `PyBool_Type`, `PyUnicode_Type`, etc.) to `boost::python::object` ?*

Seems that this works fine:

```
namespace bp = boost::python;

bp::object float_Type = bp::borrowed(
                            bp::downcast<PyTypeObject>(&PyFloat_Type))));
```

The result is that you can expose actual type objects to Python through Boost Python objects.